# Git clone hangs system

Tags: windows, git

I am using git to clone files from a remote repository.
But every time I do so my system hangs after the clone is completed.

After cloning if I try to run any commands like java -version, tasklist or any other commands then my CMD hangs resulting in system seizure.

GIT command -

```
git clone --depth 1 -b branch_name "Repo URL"
```

System Specifications -

- GIT - v2.16.2
- Windows 10
- Java - v1.8.60

Please do let me know what could be the issue.

Thanks in advance !!

Strace Information

```
--- Process 9012 created
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 00007ff876f80000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 00007ff876c40000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 00007ff873530000
--- Process 9012 thread 1560 created
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll at 00007ff876b70000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll at 00007ff874710000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll at 00007ff875530000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll at 00007ff8745f0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll at 00007ff8753a0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll at 00007ff873a10000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll at 00007ff874530000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll at 00007ff8737a0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll at 00007ff8741e0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll at 00007ff873430000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll at 00007ff874820000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libiconv-2.dll at 0000000066000000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libintl-8.dll at 0000000061cc0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libpcre-1.dll at 0000000069140000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\zlib1.dll at 0000000062e80000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libssp-0.dll at 0000000068ac0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll at 00007ff874560000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll at 00007ff874ec0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll at 00007ff873940000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll at 00007ff872d20000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll at 00007ff872760000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll at 00007ff872e30000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll at 00007ff872d40000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Program Files\McAfee\DLP\Agent\fcagpph64.dll at 00007ff843460000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll at 00007ff875590000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll at 00007ff8739c0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll at 00007ff876cf0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll at 00007ff873a30000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll at 00007ff8751d0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll at 00007ff873360000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll at 00007ff8732d0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll at 00007ff873320000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll at 00007ff874920000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll at 00007ff874810000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll at 00007ff874460000
--- Process 9012 thread 5196 created
--- Process 9012 thread 1140 created
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv at 00007ff86df00000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\version.dll at 00007ff868570000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll at 00007ff86f020000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll at 00007ff86f610000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll at 00007ff872510000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL at 00007ff8728f0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\logoncli.dll at 00007ff86fe50000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll at 00007ff8729f0000
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll at 00007ff8731d0000
--- Process 9012 thread 11572 created
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll at 00007ff872150000
--- Process 9012 thread 2428 created
--- Process 9012 thread 8804 created
--- Process 9012 loaded C:\Program Files\McAfee\DLP\Agent\fcagafa64.dll at 00007ff842dYour branch is up to date with 'origin/MYATT_ISTv4'.
20000
--- Process 9012 thread 11528 created
--- Process 9012 thread 10624 created
--- Process 9012 thread 2956 created
--- Process 9012 thread 12924 created
--- Process 9012 thread 10128 created
--- Process 9012 thread 10128 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 6236 created
--- Process 9012 thread 6236 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 13004 created
--- Process 9012 thread 13004 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 12924 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 2956 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 10624 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 11528 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 2428 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 8804 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 1140 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 5196 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 11572 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 thread 1560 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 9012 exited with status 0x0
```

Comment: Can you share the command you used? Or any output that might add context?

Comment: `strace git clone --depth 1 -b branch_name repo_url` may print some clues.

Comment: do you mean the OS hangs or the command hangs? You write system hangs, so how you start next command? Pls. update description. Thanks... (@ElpieKay, it is windows, so no 'strace')

Comment: @ĽubomírCarik `strace` is available in `git bash`, at least in version 2.8.0.

Comment: @Ľubomír Carik initially the cmd hangs then eventually OS also hangs.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\McAfee\DLP\Agent\fcagafa64.dll ` looks like your virus software is interfering, disable it and try again. If it is you may need to add an exception.

Comment: I can see a process by name "C:\Program Files\McAfee\DLP\Agent\fcagafa64.dll" -- can this be causing the hang issue ????

Comment: @Liam I am thinking the same !! added comments at the same time :).. will try that once !! but this is corporate system.. this may take some time.. will check on this though ..

Comment: Yes, I've had this before. The virus software tries to scan all files as they come in. I clone my repos into a folder that the virus software is configured to ignore. Also [antivirus software is dead and mostly a waste of time](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/may/06/antivirus-software-fails-catch-attacks-security-expert-symantec) :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the anti-virus. Once I added an exception to my AV I was able to clone without any issue.